# Not able to pass value from view to controller with jquery POST in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass text box value and Dropdown selected value as Id which user is entering through jquery POST method from view to controller, but i am not able to pass that values at some point in the code i am missing something but not able to find my mistake, also as there can be multiple records and each records display dropdownlist and textbox differently so how i will know i am using textbox with that particular id and that data from textbox saved in that particular id, i am talking about the role of `data-posid` to be used in jquery post

My code is as follows

```
 <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Item Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Reorder Level
                </th>
                <th>
                    Current
                </th>
                <th>
                    Outstanding
                </th>
                <th>
                    Supplier
                </th>
                <th>
                    Quantity
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Laundrybooking)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reorder)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currents)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Outstanding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("SIId", null, new { @data_posid="@item.POSId", @class = "form-control", @type = "text"})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-posid="@item.POSId" type="text" id="qty" class="qty form-control" placeholder="Quantity" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-posid="@item.POSId" class="addQty btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>


   $(function () {
        $('#SIId').change(function () {
            $('.addQty').click(function () {
                $.post("@Url.Action("AddQuantity", "PurchaseOrder")", { id: $(this).data('posid'), Qty: $('#qty').val(), Siid: $("select option:selected").val() })
            });   
        });
});


    public ActionResult AddQuantity(decimal? Qty, int id, int Siid)
    {
        var posid = db.SingleOrDefault<POStaging>(id);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            posid.Qty = Qty;
            posid.SIId = Siid;
            db.Update(posid);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Please help me with this

Comment: On your `DropDownList`, is there a reason why you have `null` as your `selectList` parameter? Are you doing anything to add `option`s to this?

Comment: @alansi am using this to fetch the options ViewBag.SupplierId = new SelectList(db.Fetch<SupplierItemsvw>("select si.SIId, CONCAT(su.SupplierName, '@', 'RS.', si.Price) as SupplierName from SupplierItems si " +
                "inner join Supplier su on si.SupplierId = su.SupplierId"), "SIId", "SupplierName");

Comment: Ok. I see how you retrieve the list, but how are you adding that to the `DropDownList`?

Comment: @alans i am using that SIId as id for dropdownlist which is my viewbag name

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I'm out of touch of the "magic" behind the scenes how it gets connected.

Comment: @alans i am displaying that dropdown list with Viewbag variable nothing else, but by seeing my jquery code can you tell me why i am saving value of dropdown list value and also quantity value

Comment: I know, I get it now. Sorry. I'm just trying to recall how `DropDownList` works. It's been a while :) However, I look at your code and it should check out. Did you make sure you have the `[HttpPost]` attribute above your Action?

Comment: @alans so you have any idea what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with this code

```
 $('#SIId').change(function () {
   $('.addQty').click(function () {
      $.post("@Url.Action("AddQuantity", "PurchaseOrder")", { id: $(this).data('posid'), Qty: $('#qty').val(), Siid: $("select option:selected").val() })
       });   
  });
```

Here you are registering the `click` event for the button on `onChange` event of the `DropDownList` which is fine, but it does not `triggers` the `click` event of that `button` and hence no `post` call is happening, you need to `click` on the `button` to fire the `post` call. other then that everything looks ok, I have tried this and it is posting the data.

Hope this helps or let me know if I am missing something here...
Happy coding...

Comment: It partially working i am not able to get value of dropdown list value on change i

Comment: this code can give you the selected value on `onchange` event: `$('#SIId').change(function () {
      var selectedid = $(this).val();//this will give the selected value of Drop down
  });`

Comment: but if i used on change and inside that click my click event is not getting called

Comment: I am little confused now! if you want the `selected value` of `DropDownList` and want to `post` that `onClick` on the button then use this code
`$('.addQty').click(function () {
      $.post("@Url.Action("AddQuantity", "PurchaseOrder")", { id: $(this).data('posid'), Qty: $('#qty').val(), Siid: $("select option:selected").val() })
       }); `
Take out the `onchange` method as that is not required I guess!